# Wix ICE Warning -  LGHT1076: ICE69?

Tags: xml, msbuild, wix

I have 2 projects Web Applications. when i Prepared the first build using wix and MSBuild

but when i try to do it for the second file  it did not work .... I realized that it contains same product code, upgrade code and GUID

> : warning LGHT1076: ICE69: Mismatched component reference. Entry
>   'reg8A3751B50238EDF0FACAEE74FC89759B' of the Regis try table belongs
>   to component 'cmp1A9031335E9554FB2A145276832DF1F7'. However, the
>   formatted string in column 'Value' references file
>   'filB6D67A5A6BD4F933D77F 1F20625E019D' which belongs to component
>   'cmp6AF2A0A8BF3E14CDDC849A3253AAD235'.  Components are in the same
>   feature. [C:\xx\x\x\

Edit:

Thanks man, but I am trying to delete previous  harvested Files , any clue how to do it?

```
    <Exec
        Command='"$(WixPath)candle" -ext WixIIsExtension -ext WixUtilExtension -ext WiXNetFxExtension -dpublishDir=$(Publish) -dMyWebResourceDir=. @(WixCode, &apos; &apos;)'
        ContinueOnError="false"
        WorkingDirectory="." />

    <Exec
        Command='"$(WixPath)light" -ext WixUIExtension -ext WixIIsExtension -ext WixUtilExtension -ext WiXNetFxExtension -out $(MsiOut) @(WixObject, &apos; &apos;)'
        ContinueOnError="false"
        WorkingDirectory="." />
```

Comment: Edit:

Thanks man, but I am trying to delete previous harvested Files , any clue how to do it? or how to solve this issue i had almost 832 warrnings.... 00